# Don't give / cause / let / make me wait for long?

Tags: word-choice, idiom-request

I had a case today where I really didn't know what to choose:

> *My friend*: Please, wait me on the first floor, I'm coming  soon.
>
> *I (me)*: Ok. But Don't **give / cause / let / make** me wait for long?

Which of the bold verbs is idiomatic in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly as you've written the sentences, only the last two are grammatical. However, with some slight rephrasing, all of these would be fine:

> Okay. But don't give me **a reason to** wait for long.
>   Okay. But don't **cause me to** wait for long.
>   Okay. But don't let me wait for long.
>   Okay. But don't make me wait for long.

Which you use is up to you and the specific message you want to convey.